# Can I apply gradients created from a canvas context to other canvas contexts?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Can I apply gradients created from a canvas context to other canvas contexts, like the following code?

```
var canvasContextA = document.getElementById("canvasA").getContext("2d");
var canvasContextB = document.getElementById("canvasB").getContext("2d");

var gradientFromCanvasContextA = canvasContextA.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 100, 0);
gradientFromCanvasContextA.addColorStop(0, "black");
gradientFromCanvasContextA.addColorStop(1, "white");

canvasContextB.fillStyle = gradientFromCanvasContextA;
```

Can you give me an answer based on the standard?
Is it an undefined behavior?

Comment: Not sure but personally i'd consider it risky behaviour and at a minimum you might want to "deep copy" the object first. Otherwise what should happen if the object in context A is modified or destroyed? The usual reason you would call something a "context" rather than "container" is because typically objects within the context only make sense in "that context".

Comment: @SpliFF. Yes, the concept is unusual, but ... `context.createXXXGradient` will create an independent gradient object that is not associated with a particular context (same with `context.createPattern`). It's safe to let it be used among different canvases -- not typical, but safe. Like any independent object,  destroying one reference in one canvas context will not affect the same object being used in a different canvas. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. I found this note in the [Canvas 2D Specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/):

```
In the case of addColorStop() on CanvasGradient, the "computed value of the 'color' property" for the purposes of determining the computed value of the currentColor keyword is always fully opaque black (there is no associated element). [CSSCOLOR]

This is because CanvasGradient objects are canvas-neutral — a CanvasGradient object created by one canvas can be used by another, and there is therefore no way to know which is the "element in question" at the time that the color is specified.
```

Seems to imply you can do what you ask, but only for gradients and possibly font properties.